# How to determine the SharePoint site structure to be created

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

I'm hoping to gather information about how to determine the SharePoint site structure that will be created. What steps need to be taken and what questions asked?

Which resources do you use to gather the required information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is named as Information Management. You can use below Technet Article to find more information on this process.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262900.aspx